# how to change the svn URL on a package/stack wiki page

Tags: ros, source, svn, wiki

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I wrote some documentation on the ros.org/wiki page of a stack and some packages that I created. I can't seem to figure out how to change the autogenerated 'Source:' URL that pops up at the top of the page. Right now it's pointing to trunk but I want it to point to a released version in the tags folder instead. I've noticed for a while that many official WG stacks and packages have the svn URL of trunk not of a tagged release. Why is that? I'm assuming the wiki autogenerator uses the path to the highest level package in the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH with that package name - that would put the code in trunk above a released folder in tags...but this is just a theory.

How can I change the svn URL to a tagged release?

> ...

> - Repository: penn-ros-pkg
> - Source: svn https://mediabox.grasp.upenn.edu/svn/penn-ros-pkgs/sbpl_arm_planning/trunk/sbpl_arm_planner

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9445/how-to-change-the-svn-url-on-a-package/stack-wiki-page/) by [ben](https://answers.ros.org/users/33/ben/) on ROS Answers with karma: 674 on 2011-03-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We are still working on upgrades to the indexer to enable pointing the URL to released tags.  For now, the URL will always point at whatever we point the indexer at, which is a manual process.  In the future, we will take the rosdistro specification and have multiple, per-distro index jobs to provide better information to users.

You can see an example of the richer information that will be possible here:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/common/Releases

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-03-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-03-26**:
Shoot me an e-mail and we resolve this.  The penn-ros-pkg tree needs to be reorganized in order to index correctly.

**Comment by [ben](https://answers.ros.org/users/33/ben/) on 2011-03-25**:
Now that the packages sbpl_arm_planner and sbpl_arm_planner_node have been released for unstable, how can I change where the indexer points at? (http://www.ros.org/wiki/sbpl_arm_planner and http://www.ros.org/wiki/sbpl_arm_planner_node show that the packages are in a stack called 'trunk'.